# How to load uncompressed Dojo files from Google's CDN?

Tags: dojo, google-cdn

Is there a good way to bring in the uncompressed version of a dependency using `dojo.require`? I'm already requesting `dojo.xd.uncompressed.js`, but all of the dijits I'm using, etc. are being provided in uncompressed form. Is there a flag I'm missing somwehere? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a way to do this for individual modules outside of base or prebuilt layers, that I know of.  Individual modules don't have uncompressed versions built.

If you need to debug something in dijit, you might have some success manually loading http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dijit/dijit-all.xd.js.uncompressed.js via script tag (it's the uncompressed version of a layer including most if not all dijit widgets), but realize you should never load this layer in production, as it is most likely more than you need.

(edit) of course, the other option is to download the dojo source yourself (the -src.zip or -src.tar.gz at http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.1/) and run it all on a local webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Maybie you should use something like google.load("dojo", "1.6.1", {uncompressed:true}); ?

Can you show us your header ?

http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/libraries/devguide.html#dojo

Comment: I'm not using the Google loader because I don't have an API key. Is that the only solution?

Comment: I use the solution suggested by Ken below : I have a source version downloaded into my local web server and I use it for development.